# Navigator.push duplicating screens on Stack

Tags: android, navigation, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a BottomAppBar where i am using Navigator.push(..); to call new pages.

The problem is that whenever i press an icon in the BottomAppBar it calls a new instance of the Screen which could be already existing in the Stack!

Any ideas ??

Comment: Please provide examples of your code in order to make it easier to diagnose possible solutions.

Comment: You dont need Navigator.push() to navigate using BottomAppBar(). Just use setState() to rebuild your widget when an icon got pressed.

Comment: I am using the bottom navitgation bar in a Class and then caling it on every screen that should contain the bottomnavigationbar this the code which push screens :

Comment: Class : https://scontent.fcmn2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/49841097_2150619488488838_9002014924272041984_n.png?_nc_cat=101&_nc_ht=scontent.fcmn2-1.fna&oh=54bf6b654602af4af01607c51fce1f5c&oe=5CB5C587

-------

Comment: Calling : https://scontent.fcmn2-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/50291321_372379010246584_6301116635579154432_n.png?_nc_cat=107&_nc_ht=scontent.fcmn2-2.fna&oh=d45b58f04c0bbfd6f6758c45ed28854f&oe=5CCD550B